# How to properly specify context for Drupal behaviours

Tags: theming, javascript

I have this code that does not work. I know why it does not work - first time page is loaded 'context' is all page and jquery easely finds '.view-SPECIFICVIEW .view-content'. After AJAX 'context' has changed and it is now just '.view-SPECIFICVIEW' and inside that there is no class '.view-SPECIFICVIEW' and therefore nothing happens. Script works if I remove '.view-SPECIFICVIEW' from find(), but then all views are selected.

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
    Drupal.behaviors.MYMODULE = {
      attach: function(context, settings) {
        $(context).find('.view-SPECIFICVIEW .view-content').masonry({
          columnWidth : 300,
          gutterWidth : 20
        });
      }
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

I would like to have this code to work with '.view-SPECIFICVIEW' and also I would like to know how code changes if multiple, different specific views should be targeted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stop using `context` in this case.  I've been playing around with jQuery Masonry and I've not needed to use it.

```
(function ($){
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule ={
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('.view-SPECIFICVIEW .view-content').masonry({
        columnWidth : 300,
        gutterWidth : 20      
      })    
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

FYI, I'd also take a look at the [Masonry recommendation](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html#imagesloaded_plugin) to use the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin if there are images in your view.  It takes a LOT of future frustration out.

Comment: You mean I should use attach as `attach: function()` without context and settings? Masonry is absolutely not important in this case.

Comment: You can pass context and settings through, but if you're not using them there seems little point.  I'm just saying, rather than use `$(context).find` just use  `$('.view-SPECIFICVIEW .view-content')`

Comment: `.find()` is also an extra function call, so I'd imagine it's slightly slower.  It's probably negligible though.

Comment: Ok, tested. Thanks. "Just stop using context" appears to be correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, Context acts as "live" so doing it this way will attach it to each instance of view-SPECIFICVIEW (this is if I understand what your asking)

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
    Drupal.behaviors.MYMODULE = {
      attach: function(context, settings) {
        $('.view-content',context).each(function(){
         /* ADD CODE HERE */
        });
      }
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Comment: Main problem is that there is no `.view-SPECIFICVIEW` in context after AJAX. context IS `.view-SPECIFICVIEW`. Im still waiting for a chance of real world test, any hour now.